# Configure soap:address location to domain name on IIS

Tags: wcf

I have a web service on a shared hosting running IIS. I want to run the web service on secured connection. However when I go to https://mywebsitename.com/test.svc?wsdl the soap:address address is pointing to http://servername.webhost.com/test.svc.

What am I missing? I can't get the secured connection to work.

```
<wsdl:service name="test">
   <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Itest">
       <soap:address location="http://servername.webhost.com/test.svc"/>
   </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

If I go to unsecured http://mywebsitename.com/test.svc?wsdl then it returns the domain name.

```
<wsdl:service name="test">
   <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Itest">
       <soap:address location="http://mywebsitename.com/test.svc"/>
   </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

This is how my configuration looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior >
                <serviceMetadata
                         httpGetEnabled="false"
                         httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I tried adding specifying the httpsGetUrl to the serviceMetaData

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetUrl="https://mywebsitename.com/test.svc?wsdl"
            httpGetEnabled="false"
            httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

but I get an error about multipleSiteBindingsEnabled.

```
When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint 'https://mywebsitename.com/test.svc?wsdl'.
```

If I disable multipleSiteBindingsEnabled then I get this error message.

```
This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting
```

I also changed the bindings on the frontend app.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SecurityByTransport_Itest">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <clear/>
        <endpoint address="https://mywebsitename.com/test.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="SecurityByTransport_Itest"
              contract="FrontPageService.Itest"
              name="SecurityByTransport_Itest" />

    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

However when I call the web service from the front end the inner exception has this error message.

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with all the tags you chose, but WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint configuration in web.config requires adding a binding with the address mex like this:

```
<endpoint address="mex"  
          binding="mexHttpsBinding"  
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

You can refer to [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SSL certificate is properly installed on the server and the SSL binding configuration in your service configuration file is correct.

Change

```
<soap:address location="http://servername.webhost.com/test.svc"/>
```

To

```
<soap:address location="https://mywebsitename.com/test.svc"/>
```